# Putting two divs tags next to each other

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

so I am trying to put these two s of class= "Col" next to each other with the image in the full left side of the screen.
this is the component code:

```js
import batta from '../../Images/batta.png';
import onlineAuction from '../../Images/onlineAuction.png';
import './LandingScreen.css';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Container,Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
const LandingScreen = ()=>{

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  
    return(
       <Container>
           <Row>
               <Col>
                    <img src ={batta}/>
               </Col>
               <Col>
                    <form style={{marginLeft:300}}>
                        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document" style={{"display":"flex"}}>
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <h5 className="modal-title">Sign In</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <fieldset  style={{maxWidth:500 , marginLeft:20}}> 
                                            <div className="form-group" style={{marginTop :25}}>
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"
                                                value={email} onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group" style={{marginTop :1}}>
                                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label mt-4">Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"
                                                value={password} onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-footer">
                                    <Link to ="/register" style={{marginRight:175}}>
                                        Don't have an account
                                    </Link>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" >
                                        Log In
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </form>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        
        </Container>
    );
};


export default LandingScreen;
```

and this is how it looks on the browser:[Component rendered in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Ck2.png)

i thought of using this css code but it didn't work.

```css
#leftHalf{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 63%

}

.image-container{
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.rightHalf{
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    
}
```

please i would be so grateful if you give me a hand in this problem since i still don't master css very well.

Comment: did you try align-items: center on the image container?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that works?

Comment: In general, you don't provide your stylesheet, which is the issue here, and your snippets don't work. Obviously it's something that has to do with the parent elements and through the parent elements you can style your Cols